# Associating an Access Control List with an Application Load Balancer in AWS

Tags: amazon-waf, amazon-acl, amazon-alb

In AWS I've created an Access Control List as part of setting up a WAF.

I have several Application Load Balancers (found in EC2 under Load Balancers).

None of these appear as options in the dropdown list for associating an ACL to an ALB, in fact when trying to associate the dropdown list is empty.

[image: screenshot of trying to link an application load balancer to an access control list]

Everything shares the same region, so I am unsure why these application load balancers are not being seen.

I'm not sure if it is relevant but the ALBs are listed as type "Classic".

I've found the amazon documentation to be lacking in this department, any help would be appreciated.